# MySQL Run A Automatic script

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL database with two tables in it: drivers and devices

The drivers table has a field called expiration date.
The devices table has a field called status.

My goal is to create a event that will :

- Get current Date
- Compare drivers (expiration date) with current date
- If the expiration date is passed then it needs to change the status of the device to 'EXP'

Is something like this possible?
It is like a expiration check

Comment: Why not use a cronjob for this?

Comment: [Using the Event Scheduler](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/) - study.

Comment: @NicoHaase There is a built-in event system in `MySQL` so using `crontab jobs`, although possible, is unpracticle. It is like calling a `bash` script to run a `curl` request from python.

Comment: @Mr_Tropica please note for future questions. Whenever you are asking a `MySQL` question, provide the `CREATE TABLE` queries for the related tables so that we don't have to re-construct your database from scratch and possibly miss something. It is a waste of effort on the community's part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so considering the following `MySQL` Table Structure:

```
CREATE TABLE Devices (
    device_id INT PRIMARY KEY,
    status ENUM('ACTIVE', 'EXPIRED')
);

CREATE TABLE Drivers (
    driver_id INT PRIMARY KEY,
    device_id INT,
    expiration_date DATE,
    FOREIGN KEY (device_id) REFERENCES Devices(device_id)
);
```

You'd need to run through each driver, see if it has expired and update the device properly.

First, you need to enable `EVENTS` in your database:

```
SET GLOBAL event_scheduler = ON;
```

Next, you can just create an `event` that runs each day, checks all the `active` devices for `expired` drivers and updates appropriately:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE EVENT UpdateDeviceStatus
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 DAY
STARTS CURRENT_DATE
DO
BEGIN
    UPDATE Devices d
    SET d.status = 'EXPIRED'
    WHERE EXISTS (
        SELECT 1 FROM Drivers dr
        WHERE dr.device_id = d.device_id
        AND dr.expiration_date < CURRENT_DATE
    ) AND d.status = 'ACTIVE';
END;
//    
DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the query your event will need to execute:

```
UPDATE devices
SET `status` = 'EXP'
WHERE EXISTS
(
    SELECT 1
    FROM drivers
    JOIN device_drivers
    ON drivers.id = device_drivers.driver_id AND
       device_drivers.device_id = devices.id
    WHERE drivers.`expiration date` < now()
);
```

As about the creation of the event, you have multiple options, some of which are listed here:

- [event scheduler](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/) (courtesy to @Akina)
- [cron job](https://dbperf.wordpress.com/2010/04/05/scheduling-a-mysql-stored-procedure-using-a-linux-cron-job-and-mysql-events/)
- [heartbeat pattern](https://www.techtarget.com/searchdatacenter/definition/Heartbeat)
- you can even have some UI or other event that would trigger the call to this

Whatever the case, you may want to wrap your `UPDATE` into a [stored procedure](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-procedure.html) and you may also want to wrap a [transaction](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/commit.html) around the call of this event, especially if there are more write operations.